# Python3 aiohttp - invalid character in header

Tags: python, aiohttp

I am getting the error "invalid character in header" whilst using aiohttp on some websites even when using their example code. Some websites work, others don't. They work fine using the requests package though. Any ideas?

```
#Example code
async def main():

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get('https://www.rockhamptonregion.qld.gov.au/Home') as response:

            print("Status:", response.status)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Traceback example:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python Projects/test2.py", line 35, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
  File "C:\Users\P\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:/Python Projects/test2.py", line 26, in main
    async with session.get('https://www.rockhamptonregion.qld.gov.au/Home') as response:
  File "C:\Users\P\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 1117, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "C:\Users\P\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 544, in _request
    await resp.start(conn)
  File "C:\Users\P\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client_reqrep.py", line 892, in start
    raise ClientResponseError(
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientResponseError: 400, message='invalid character in header', url=URL('https://www.rockhamptonregion.qld.gov.au/Home')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least from `curl` I see this.

```plaintext
$ curl -s --head https://www.rockhamptonregion.qld.gov.au/Home \
    | grep -A 1 ___utmv | xxd
00000000: 5365 742d 436f 6f6b 6965 3a20 5f5f 5f75  Set-Cookie: ___u
00000010: 746d 766d 4c49 4275 7342 4545 5a3d 5a45  tmvmLIBusBEEZ=ZE
00000020: 785a 6470 426c 7776 703b 2070 6174 683d  xZdpBlwvp; path=
00000030: 2f3b 204d 6178 2d41 6765 3d39 3030 0d0a  /; Max-Age=900..
00000040: 5365 742d 436f 6f6b 6965 3a20 5f5f 5f75  Set-Cookie: ___u
00000050: 746d 7661 4c49 4275 7342 4545 5a3d 6d6e  tmvaLIBusBEEZ=mn
00000060: 4e01 6843 6343 3b20 7061 7468 3d2f 3b20  N.hCcC; path=/; 
00000070: 4d61 782d 4167 653d 3930 300d 0a53 6574  Max-Age=900..Set
00000080: 2d43 6f6f 6b69 653a 205f 5f5f 7574 6d76  -Cookie: ___utmv
00000090: 624c 4942 7573 4245 455a 3d4f 5a54 0d0a  bLIBusBEEZ=OZT..
000000a0: 2020 2020 5865 4f4f 6461 6c5a 3a20 7a74      XeOOdalZ: zt
000000b0: 673b 2070 6174 683d 2f3b 204d 6178 2d41  g; path=/; Max-A
000000c0: 6765 3d39 3030 0d0a                      ge=900..
```

There is this group of 3 cookies whose names start with "___utmv". Here are what the values supposed to be.

```py
>>> l = [
...     '5a45785a6470426c777670',
...     '6d6e4e0168436343',
...     '5a540d0a2020202058654f4f64616c5a3a207a7467',
... ]
>>> list(map(bytes.fromhex, l))
[b'ZExZdpBlwvp', b'mnN\x01hCcC', b'ZT\r\n    XeOOdalZ: ztg']
```

The first one is fine, the last seems malformed, but might be interpreted as another cookie, but the middle one is clearly violates HTTP RFC 2616 which in [4.2 Message Headers](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616#section-4.2) defines a message header as:

> ```
>   message-header = field-name ":" [ field-value ]
>   field-name     = token
>   field-value    = *( field-content | LWS )
>   field-content  = <the OCTETs making up the field-value
>                    and consisting of either *TEXT or combinations
>                    of token, separators, and quoted-string>
> ```

`b'\x01'` matches none of `TEXT`, `token`, `separators` or `quoted-string`.

It may be a bug, or they don't want you to parse them. And if you still want to do that you might look for a more permissive HTTP client. For instance, stdlib `urllib` seems okay with that.

```py
>>> from urllib.request import urlopen
... 
... resp = urlopen('https://www.rockhamptonregion.qld.gov.au/Home')
... [(k, v) for (k, v) in resp.getheaders() if v.startswith('___utmv')]
[('Set-Cookie', '___utmvmLIBusBEEZ=INQnabCZqUC; path=/; Max-Age=900'),
 ('Set-Cookie', '___utmvaLIBusBEEZ=ekS\x01bOgT; path=/; Max-Age=900'),
 ('Set-Cookie',
  '___utmvbLIBusBEEZ=aZI\r\n    XdBOPalz: vtB; path=/; Max-Age=900')]
```